# Can I add to the format pulldown in tinyMCE within wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, tinymce

Deperately trying to find a way to add some styles to the format pull down in the tinyMCE. I have worked out how to strip out the ones I do not need with

```
    <?php
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'set_blockformats');

function set_blockformats($settings)
{

    $settings['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = "p,h3";

    return $settings;
}

?>
```

but if I try to add my own style, say `<div class="someClass">`, I just get an empty line in the pulldown that seems to have no effect on the HTML of the selected text.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. What you are looking for [is the formats setting](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/formats). Here is an example (you need to make sure that the classes you want to use are to be found inside the css file you set with [the custom_css setting](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/content_css)):

```
// Style formats you want to add
formats: [{
    title: 'Title1'
}, {
    title: 'CSS_1',
    block: 'p',
    classes: 'class1',
    exact: true
}, {
    title: 'CSS_2',
    block: 'p',
    classes: 'class2',
    exact: true
}, {
    title: 'CSS_§',
    inline: 'span',
    classes: 'class3',
        exact: true
}],
```

PHP for wordpress should be:

```
$settings['formats'] = "[{
        title: 'Title1'
    }, {
        title: 'CSS_1',
        block: 'p',
        classes: 'class1',
        exact: true
    }, {
        title: 'CSS_2',
        block: 'p',
        classes: 'class2',
        exact: true
    }, {
        title: 'CSS_§',
        inline: 'span',
        classes: 'class3',
            exact: true
    }]";
```

Comment: but how do I add this in wordpress without hacking the core?

Comment: this produced errors until it is condensed to one line, then it has not effect.

Comment: weird, well iam not very familiar with wordpress, but maybe this helps you http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-custom-styles-to-format-dropdown-in-tinymce-editor

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying the insert `blockquote` format, **not** block. There's no such tag AFAIW. Just the way you already do it but add `blockquote` to the list!

Comment: Sorry, should be been more clear. I want to be able to add divs with custom classes. Have updated the question to show this.

Comment: Well then `theme_advanced_blockformats` is not your solution. This only sets the container tag. I believe it won't work the way you hope without some hard coded functionality.